# how to make two button to open two activity

Tags: android

```
package com.example.luke.sinhalasindu;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


    public class HomePage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        Button bntoartistpage;
        Button bntonewmp3page;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

            bntoartistpage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntoartistpage);
            bntoartistpage.setOnClickListener(this);

            bntonewmp3page = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntonewmp3page);
            bntonewmp3page.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent inent = new Intent(this, Artist.class);

            // calling an activity using <intent-filter> action name
            //  Intent inent = new Intent("com.example.luke.sinhalasindu");
            startActivity(inent); }

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent inent = new Intent(this, NewMp3.class);
            // calling an activity using <intent-filter> action name
            //  Intent inent = new Intent("com.example.luke.sinhalasindu");
            startActivity(inent); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's issue? What have you tried? And where are you stuck?

Comment: You have used wrong way to implement button onclick method.

Comment: I want to open a layout from a button
and other layout from another button

Comment: You can't override onClick twice. Check my answer.

Comment: @luke check my answer below and try

Comment: What's issue with that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this code:

```
 bntoartistpage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntoartistpage);
        bntoartistpage.setOnClickListener(this);

        bntonewmp3page = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntonewmp3page);
        bntonewmp3page.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Try this code

```
bntoartistpage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntoartistpage);
         bntoartistpage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent inent = new Intent(HomePage.this, Artist.class);

                // calling an activity using <intent-filter> action name
                //  Intent inent = new Intent("com.example.luke.sinhalasindu");
                startActivity(inent);
            }
        });

bntonewmp3page = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntonewmp3page);
bntonewmp3page.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent inent = new Intent(HomePage.this, NewMp3.class);
                // calling an activity using <intent-filter> action name
                //  Intent inent = new Intent("com.example.luke.sinhalasindu");
                startActivity(inent); 
            }
        });
```

And also declare these two `Activity` classes `Artist` and `NewMp3` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file like this:

```
<activity android:name=" com.example.luke.sinhalasindu.Artist" />
<activity android:name=" com.example.luke.sinhalasindu.NewMp3" />
```

Comment: Can you edit answer to include a note that he would need to register those activities in Manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* override `onClick` method *twice*. Either use inner class for `setOnClickListener` or use this approach:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent inent = null;
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bntoartistpage:
            intent = new Intent(ThisAct.this, Activity1.class);      
        break;
        case R.id.bntonewmp3page:
            intent = new Intent(ThisAct.this, Activity2.class);            
        break;
    }
    startActivity(inent); 
}
```

And register new activities in manifest properly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative way to do this: use switch-case inside onclick() to choose the action. v.getId() will return the id of clicked button.

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId()) {
           case R.id.bntoartistpage:
           // do stuff;
           Intent inent = new Intent(HomePage.this, Artist.class);
           startActivity(inent);
           break;
           case R.id.bntonewmp3page:
           // do stuff;
           Intent inent = new Intent(HomePage.this, NewMp3.class);
           startActivity(inent);
           break;

   }
```

Comment: are you using the code as is? especially the "HomePage.this" inside intent ??

Comment: have you registered those activities in the manifest? if all the above things done.. then what the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand from your code you are confused about

> How to handle multiple Button listener overriding the onClick() method?

All you have to do is, you have to apply any decision making logic like `if-else` or `switch-case` inside the `onClick()` method as follow

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

    case R.id.bntoartistpage:
        Intent inent = new Intent(this, Artist.class);
        startActivity(inent);
        break;

    case R.id.bntonewmp3page:
        Intent inent = new Intent(this, NewMp3.class);
        startActivity(inent); 
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simplest way to make two or more different buttons to do same activity.

When you implement `OnClickListener` to the `Activity` or `Fragment` you just have to write `onClick()` method once.. **Not like one method for one button.** you can handle all `OnClickListener` into that method..

So in your case you can write your code like below.

```
public class HomePage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button bntoartistpage;
Button bntonewmp3page;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        bntoartistpage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntoartistpage);
        bntoartistpage.setOnClickListener(this);

        bntonewmp3page = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntonewmp3page);
        bntonewmp3page.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.bntoartistpage:
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NEWCLASS.class)); 
        break;
        case R.id.bntonewmp3page:
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), NEWCLASS.class)); 
        break;
        case R.id.OTHERCASES:
            //other functions
        break;

        default:
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: @luke : please refer to this.. this may help you.